# Sort by A-Z Product List Page in Magento 2?

Tags: custom-attributes, sorting, magento2.4.5, toolbar

I am adding below code but sort not shwoing  in frontend.

unable to add sort by A-Z

Comment: please share code.

Comment: <?php
// File: app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/Block/Product/ProductList/Toolbar.php

namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Block\Product\ProductList;

class Toolbar extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
{
    protected function _getAvailableOrders()
    {
        $orders = parent::_getAvailableOrders();
        $orders['name'] = __('Name: A-Z');
        return $orders;
    }
}

Comment: hi dear i will explain in detail and also create a module for your requirement. so please check my module.

Comment: Can we sort A-Z by default in specific category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello dear i will share my code that is working so please you check it.

/var/www/html/walletmetamask/app/code/Test/Uiform/etc/di.xml add below  code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" type="Test\Uiform\Plugin\Catalog\Block\Toolbar" />
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config">
    <plugin name="custom_sortby_add_options" type="Test\Uiform\Plugin\Catalog\Model\Config" />
</type>
</config>
```

Created new file app/code/Test/Uiform/Plugin/Catalog/Block/Toolbar.php

```
<?php
namespace Test\Uiform\Plugin\Catalog\Block;

class Toolbar extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
{

    /**
     * Set collection to pager
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
     */
    public function setCollection($collection)
    {
        $this->_collection = $collection;

        $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());

        // we need to set pagination only if passed value integer and more that 0
        $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
        if ($limit) {
            $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
        }
        if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
            if (($this->getCurrentOrder()) == 'position') {
                $this->_collection->addAttributeToSort(
                    $this->getCurrentOrder(),
                    $this->getCurrentDirection()
                );
            } else {
                if ($this->getCurrentOrder() == 'name_Z_to_A') {
                    $this->_collection->setOrder('name', 'desc');
                }elseif ($this->getCurrentOrder() == 'name_A_to_Z') {
                    $this->_collection->setOrder('name', 'asc');
                }
               //elseif ($this->getCurrentOrder() == 'high_to_low') {
                //    $this->_collection->setOrder('price', 'desc');
                //}elseif ($this->getCurrentOrder() == 'low_to_high') {
                 //   $this->_collection->setOrder('price', 'asc');
               // }
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

}
```

created new file app/code/Test/Uiform/Plugin/Catalog/Model/Config.php

```
<?php

namespace Test\Uiform\Plugin\Catalog\Model;

class Config
{
public function afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig, $options)
    {
       
        unset($options['name']);
        //unset($options['price']);

        //New sorting options
        $customOption['name_Z_to_A'] = __( 'Product Name:Z-A' );
        $customOption['name_A_to_Z'] = __( 'Product Name:A-Z' );
        //$customOption['high_to_low'] = __( 'Price High to Low' );
        //$customOption['low_to_high'] = __( 'Price Low to High' );    
        // $customOption['name'] = $default_options['name'];

        //Merge default sorting options with custom options
        $options = array_merge($customOption, $options);

        return $options;
    }
}
```

after apply below commands.

```
sudo php bin/magento s:up && sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile && sudo php bin/magento s:static-content:de -f && sudo php bin/magento c:f && sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated
```

that code working for my magento version 2.4.6-p3 and i will share product list shreen shot.

[image]
[image]

I hope that is working. so please accept my answer and give me upvote.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Can we sort the specific category alphabetically A-Z by default?

Comment: now i am implementation your requirement in my module working already, but sometimes get issues. so now I am working on it.

Comment: Please let me know if we can do this.

Answer (score 0):

hello dear please go to this file and change below code. app/code/Test/Uiform/Plugin/Catalog/Model/Config.php

```
<?php

namespace Test\Uiform\Plugin\Catalog\Model;

   class Config
  {
   protected $_registry;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
) {
$this->_registry = $registry;
}

public function afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig, $options)
    {
       
       $category = $this->_registry->registry('current_category');//get current category
       //$category->getId();

       if($category->getId() == '14'){

        unset($options['name']);
        //unset($options['price']);

        //New sorting options
        $customOption['name_Z_to_A'] = __( 'Product Name:Z-A' );
        $customOption['name_A_to_Z'] = __( 'Product Name:A-Z' );

        // $customOption['name'] = $default_options['name'];

        //Merge default sorting options with custom options
        $options = array_merge($customOption, $options);

        return $options;

        }
        else{

            $customOption['name'] = ['name'];

        //Merge default sorting options with custom options
        $options = array_merge($customOption, $options);

        return $options;
        }
    }
  }
```

above code
$category->getId() == '14' is you want your particulate category id.

after apply all below commands.

```
sudo php bin/magento s:up && sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile && sudo php bin/magento s:static-content:de -f && sudo php bin/magento c:f && sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated
```

dear, I am not sure that is works so you can try and implementation your logic. if you like my answer then accept and upvote me.

Comment: I tried above code but not working

Comment: ok i know i am also said  to you